# How to set Excel column format by ActiveX from IE

Tags: html, excel, activex

I use this code to export table in HTML to excel by ActiveX copy and paste.

I need to set all in column B to text format because content in be contain 0 as first character when export excel cut 0 out.    I try I `objWorksheet.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "@";` 
before line `objWorksheet.columns.autofit;` but it not work 00001 display as 1

```
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var userProfile = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\xx.xls");
var thisTable = document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML;
window.clipboardData.setData("Text", thisTable);
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application");
//objExcel.visible = true;
var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add();
objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(2);
objWorkSheet.Select;
objWorkSheet.Delete;
objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(2);
objWorkSheet.Select;
objWorkSheet.Delete;
var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1);
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate;
objWorksheet.name = "xxxxx";
objWorksheet.Paste;
objWorksheet.columns.autofit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer by add `objWorksheet.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "00000";` 
before line `objWorksheet.columns.autofit;`